# Change color of any word in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the color of any Expression like: "Hello" or "asdfujihasdfui". E.g I want "Hello" to appear green and "World" to appear red.
I know that it is possible to change the color of certain language keywords, comments/strings etc, but i want to be able to assign any word to any color.

Thx in advance.

Comment: use extension **Highlight**

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the "todoHighlight" extension. You just have to download it and then go to settings.json and write it like this:

```
"todohighlight.keywords": [
    {
        
        "text": "someText1",
        "color": "#ff0000",
        "backgroundColor": ""


    },
    {
        "text": "someText2",
        "color": "red",
        "backgroundColor": ""
    },
```